# How is working the build pipeline folder system?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to understand how the build system works in Azure DevOps:

Let me first shows my YAML

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

name: $(Date:yy).$(Date:MM).$(Rev:r)

trigger: 
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: NyGetCommand Restore
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

And now the error on last task:

```
##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
```

After some checking on my logs, I realized that the build (VSBuild@1) is not playing in the same folder than the publish (VSBuild@1).

> Build is happening in D:\a\1\s

> Publish is looking in D:\a\1\a

Why is it working like this? Where can I control this. What are official folders. Where can I find a depp documentation about these agents and folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below step, you're specifying the folder to publish. Specifically, you're trying to publish `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

```yaml
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

But when you haven't staged an artifact yet, there will not be any information in there.

Here's the description of the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` variable:

> The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. For example: `c:\agent_work\1\a`
>
> A typical way to use this folder is to publish your build artifacts with the [Copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files) and [Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts) tasks.
>
> Note: Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory and Build.StagingDirectory are interchangeable. This directory is purged before each new build, so you don't have to clean it up yourself.
>
> See [Artifacts in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/artifacts).
>
> This variable is agent-scoped, and can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as part of the build number or as a version control tag.

Chances are you're missing something like the first task from this [Example: Copy and publish binaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example-copy-and-publish-binaries).

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    contents: '**/$(BuildConfiguration)/**/?(*.exe|*.dll|*.pdb)'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: drop
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful explanation. In fact, the CopyFiles@2 task is already what I'm doing but I was hoping for a better solution as this copy is never mentioned in any template, documentation or tutorial of Microsoft. This is the first time I get an "official" confirmation this copy must be added. Thank you for all the links. I will read all this.